# How do I interpolate curves in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

Imagine a vectorialized typographic "C" which stroke width varies along the curve, as it often happens in typography.

I'd like to draw a curve between those two boundary curves in such a way that each point of the curve is at the same distance ratio from these two curves, for example it is always at the midpoint (distance from outer = distance from inner) or at 33% (distance from outer = twice the distance from inner).

Tracing several different curves with different distance ratios will produce a series of "concentric" curves that gradually change in shape from the outher curve from the inner curve, a little like the lanes of a street seen in a distorted perspective.

(While I used the fixed ratios procedure to let you all understand the desired result, other methods that produce a similar result are fine.)

How can this be done in Illustrator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood your question properly, it sounds like you are describing a Step Blend.

Try this . . .

1. Type a letter C, and do *Object > Expand* to give you outlines, set no fill and set a thin stroke so you can see it.
2. Using the Direct Selection tool <kbd>A</kbd> (black arrow), select and delete, the end segments.

For example

[image]

3. Do *Object > Compound path > Release*, then *Object > Ungroup*
4. Select both curved pieces
5. Do *Object > Blend > Make*
6. Do *Object > Blend > Blend Options* - and choose "Specified Steps" and set the number of steps required

[image]

7. Note: a Step Blend is a path effect, so if you want to bake in the effect to give you actual curves you can edit, then do *Object > Expand*

Step Blends also work with any curves, not just those created from letters, and also with shapes

[image]

[image]

Comment: @kexxgem Well, yes in extreme cases perhaps. This shouldn't be a problem for what the OP is asking though.  I prefer not to overcomplicate answers with extra detail like this TBH, otherwise I'd need to write a whole book on every question.